# Test connection from iis7 to mssql sample script or webpage

Tags: sql-server, iis-7

I have a test server. I need to know if websites can connect to mssql server locally.

I can telnet mssql on its port. What I need is a test page (html or asp of some sort) that resides on the IIS webserver and test a connection locally to mssql. I'm not a programmer.

Anyone can give a simple script/html where I put username/databasename/password and just show if connection succesfull or failed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an ASP file:

```
    <%
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=<MSSQL Server IP>;Database=<Database Name>;UID=<Database User>;PWD=<Database User Password>;"
    cn.CommandTimeout = 900
    cn.Close
    Response.write("Connected Successfully")
    %>
```

Comment: <%
    Set cn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=<localhost>;Database=<testdb>;UID=<testuser>;PWD=<testpasswd>;" 
    cn.CommandTimeout = 900
    cn.Close
    Response.write("Connected Successfully")
    %>                                                                    Should I remove the < and > ? then save it as test.asp ?